# List all base classes in a hierarchy of given class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, oop, introspection

Given a class `Foo` (whether it is a [new-style](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) class or not), how do you generate **all** the base classes - anywhere in the inheritance hierarchy - it [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=issubclass#issubclass) of?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

[`inspect.getmro(cls)`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) works for both new and old style classes and returns the same as `NewClass.mro()`: a list of the class and all its ancestor classes, in the order used for method resolution.

```
>>> class A(object):
>>>     pass
>>>
>>> class B(A):
>>>     pass
>>>
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(B)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for pyobjc classes :(

File "/Users/rbp/Projects/zzzzzzz/macmdtypes.py", line 70, in coerce
    print inspect.getmro(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 348, in getmro
    _searchbases(cls, result)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 339, in _searchbases
    for base in cls.__bases__:
AttributeError: '__NSTaggedDate' object has no attribute '__bases__'

Comment: @rbp I suspect that you had the same problem that I encountered: you were trying to do `inspect.getmro(obj)` instead of `inspect.getmro(type(obj))`.

Comment: What is "mro" ?

Comment: @BenSlade Method Resolution Order: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: `mro` is "method resolution order". Also, it is not needed to import `inspect`.  You can simply call `mro()` or `__mro__` on any of your classes (but only `mro()` on types)!  In other words, the solution here can simply be `B.mro()`.  It won't be shown with `dir(B)`, but it's there!

Answer (score 53):

See the [`__bases__` property](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) available on a python `class`, which contains a tuple of the bases classes:

```
>>> def classlookup(cls):
...     c = list(cls.__bases__)
...     for base in c:
...         c.extend(classlookup(base))
...     return c
...
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> class B(A): pass
...
>>> class C(object, B): pass
...
>>> classlookup(C)
[<type 'object'>, <class __main__.B at 0x00AB7300>, <class __main__.A at 0x00A6D630>]
```

Comment: This may introduce duplicates. And this is why the documentation for `getmro` explicitly says "No class appears more than once in this tuple"?

Comment: Caution, `__bases__` only goes up **one level**.  (As your recursive utility implies, but a cursory glance at the example might not pick up on that.)

Answer (score 44):

`inspect.getclasstree()` will create a nested list of classes and their bases. 
Usage:

```
inspect.getclasstree(inspect.getmro(IOError)) # Insert your Class instead of IOError.
```

Comment: Ooh, nice. And for even nicer output, use pprint! `python -c 'import inspect; from pprint import pprint as pp; pp(inspect.getclasstree(inspect.getmro(IOError)))'`

Answer (score 31):

According to the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes), we can also simply use `class.__mro__` attribute or `class.mro()` method:

```py
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> object.__mro__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>>
>>> B.mro()
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> A.mro()
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> object.mro()
[<class 'object'>]
>>> A in B.mro()
True
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use the `__bases__` tuple of the class object:

```
class A(object, B, C):
    def __init__(self):
       pass
print A.__bases__
```

The tuple returned by `__bases__` has all its base classes.

Comment: If your class inherits from a class that inherits from a class, only the first part of the chain will be in its `__bases__`

Comment: Simple and clean without importing a whole module for a single function.

Comment: @Temperosa it maybe be simple and clean but it's wrong

Answer (score 19):

> In python 3.7 you don't need to import inspect, type.mro will give you the result.

```
>>> class A:
...   pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   pass
... 
>>> type.mro(B)
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>>>
```

attention that in python 3.x every class inherits from base object class.

Comment: Same thing seems to apply in my case as in @esmit's comment on the [answer currently below this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401900): `type.mro(my_obj)` fails with `TypeError: descriptor 'mro' for 'type' objects doesn't apply to a 'my_obj' object`; `type.mro(type(my_obj))` works. Not sure if that's relevant: `my_obj` is an instance of a Pydantic model.

Comment: According to [YaOzI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965847/2932052), there is no need to import anything when using the [`mro()` method (or `__mro__` attribute) of the class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes). Is there an advantage in using `type.mro()`?

Answer (score 2):

Although Jochen's answer is very helpful and correct, as you can obtain the class hierarchy using the .getmro() method of the inspect module, it's also important to highlight that Python's inheritance hierarchy is as follows:

ex:

```
class MyClass(YourClass):
```

**An inheriting class**

- Child class
- Derived class
- Subclass

ex:

```
class YourClass(Object):
```

**An inherited class**

- Parent class
- Base class
- Superclass

One class can inherit from another
 - The class' attributed are inherited
 - in particular, its methods are inherited
 - this means that instances of an inheriting (child) class can access attributed of the inherited (parent) class

instance -> class -> then inherited classes

using

```
import inspect
inspect.getmro(MyClass)
```

will show you the hierarchy, within Python.