# How do I inspect a Python's class hierarchy?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pydev, hierarchy

Assuming I have a class X, how do I check which is the base class/classes, and their base class/classes etc?

I'm using Eclipse with PyDev, and for Java for example you could type CTRL + T on a class' name and see the hierarchy, like:

```
java.lang.Object
   java.lang.Number
       java.lang.Integer
```

Is it possible for Python?

If not possible in Eclipse PyDev, where can I find this information?

Comment: This is answered in [Python: List all base classes in a hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/python-list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hit f4 with class name highlighted to open hierarchy view.

Answer (score 8):

Try [inspect.getclasstree()](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclasstree).

Answer (score 7):

Also, every class carries around with it an attribute called [`__mro__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) which gives all the parent classes from which a given class could inherit methods or attributes. Read them from left to right. For example:

```python
assert bool.__mro__ == (<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
assert True.__class__.__mro__ == (<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: Also every (new style) class has a `mro` method, so you can call `bool.mro()` and `True.__class__.mro()` respectively (it returns list instead of tuple).

Answer (score 2):

You can also visualize class hierarchy as a picture.
I use [Graphviz DOT](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/dot/) and [pyreverse](https://pypi.org/project/pyreverse/) to visualize and explore a large mess of classes (an [example](https://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2014/09/python-visualise-your-class-hierarchy.html)).

Assuming you want to draw all classes from `tree.py` in [`parso`](https://parso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/parser-tree.html) library:

```sh
# Generate classes_tree_full.png with full UML-style class boxes
$ pyreverse -mn    -o png -p tree_full  Lib\site-packages\parso\python\tree.py

# Generate classes_tree_short.png with only class names in boxes
$ pyreverse -mn -k -o png -p tree_short Lib\site-packages\parso\python\tree.py
```

Change `-mn` to `-my` if you want to see qualified class names, ex. `parso.python.tree.Literal` instead of just `Literal`.
Note: `pyreverse` also supports multiple files via [`glob`](https://github.com/begin/globbing#what-is-globbing)patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Hit command+o, then Press Ctrl+O to show parent hierarchy

checkout this blog http://pydev.blogspot.jp/2015/03/navigating-through-your-code-when-in.html