# Multiple inheritance and Django Form

Tags: python, django-forms

Why this code doesn't work?
I see in debugger (PyCharm) that **init** line is executed but nothing more.
I have tried to put there raise exception to be really sure and again nothing happend.

```
class polo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(polo, self).__init__()
        self.po=1     <- this code is newer executed

class EprForm(forms.ModelForm, polo):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Epr
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What errors etc are you getting?

Comment: Absolutely none errors. The code is simply not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [multiple inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) so in general Python will look for methods in left-to-right order. So if your class do not have `__init__` it'll look for it in `ModelForm` and that (only if not found) in `polo`. In your code the `polo.__init__` is never called because `ModelForm.__init__` is called.

To call the constructors of both base classes use explicit constructor call:

```
class EprForm(forms.ModelForm, polo):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) # Call the constructor of ModelForm
        polo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) # Call the constructor of polo

    class Meta:
        model = models.Epr
```

Comment: Thank you very mach. It's logical now, when I see your answer. I don't know why a supposed that __init__ is some special method and will by called for every inherited class.
And with knowledge from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/python-list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy I will be able to call __init__ functions of all base classes.
Great work!