# Get fully qualified name of a Python class (Python 3.3+)

Tags: python, inspect

How can I get name of class including full path from its module root? For Python 3.3 and up?

Here is example of Python code:

```
class A:
    class B:
        class C:
            def me(self):
                print(self.__module__)
                print(type(self).__name__)
                print(repr(self))

x = A.B.C()
x.me()
```

This code outputs me on Python 3.3:

```
__main__
C
<__main__.A.B.C object at 0x0000000002A47278>
```

So, Python internally knows that my object is `__main__.A.B.C`, but how can I get this programmatically? I can parse `repr(self)`, but it sounds like a hack for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/python-list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy-of-given-class please look there for usage info via the `__bases__` attribute and `inspect`module offerings the method resolution order (`mro`) is also interesting info besides the formal inheritance chain "display". As this rules which method (in case multiple are offered) will be chosen kind of like an effective hierarchy.

Comment: Check the [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3155-qualified-name-for-classes-and-functions) attribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__qualname__) (introduced in Python 3.3):

```
class A:
    class B:
        class C:
            def me(self):
                print(self.__module__)
                print(type(self).__name__)
                print(type(self).__qualname__)
                print(repr(self))
```

Comment: D'oh. I've looked for this attribute and tried to find it using IPython, but tab completion did not show it at all. Not sure why.