# Finding Python base classes with static analysis and Jedi

Tags: python, static-analysis, python-jedi

**Note:** I don't consider this a duplicate of questions such as [List all base classes in a hierarchy of given class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy-of-given-class), because I don't have the ability to instantiate classes at run-time. The focus here is on static analysis, not dynamic.

I'm using the Jedi tool for some static analysis on internal source code. Can I use it to help me identify all the classes that a given class inherits from?

For example, here's a script called `utils.py`:

```
class UtilBase:
    pass


class SampleUtil(UtilBase):
    pass
```

Here's the code to ingest it:

```
import jedi

script = jedi.Script('utils.py')
names = script.get_names()
sample = names[1]

# shows "utils"
print(sample.parent())

# shows "SampleUtil()"
print(sample.get_signatures()[0].to_string())
```

What I want is a way to get the Name "UtilBase" from `sample`.

Comment: Jedi currently does not support this use case.