# check if two items are of the same superclass in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm making a game in Python and I want to check if two instantiated objects have the same superclass. For example if I have a class `superclass1` and two subclasses of that superclass called `sub1` and `sub2`, I want to see if an instance of `sub1` and an instance of `sub2` are both instances of `superclass1`. Is there a command for this?

Comment: list intersection using the instance's class `__base__` (or `__mro__` )? (e.g. something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy-of-given-class should probably give you enough information to do what you need)

Comment: EVERY pair of objects in Python share a superclass - `object`, if nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `isinstance` function for this

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class ChildA(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class ChildB(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


# instantiate the child class
child_a = ChildA()
# check if that child class is an instance of the parent class
print(isinstance(child_a, Parent))
# => True
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that lol

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer works for you, please mark it as 'Accepted' so that others know this question has been answered